# SharePoint Online: Due to organizational policies, you can't access this resource from this untrusted device

Tags: sharepoint-online, security

I am configuring an Office 365 tenant with Microsoft Purview sensitivity labels and I configured a Label that blocks access from unmanaged devices.

I configured my PC to be compliant, adding it to the Azure AD (using System Settings --> Accounts --> Access work or school).

In Intune, the PC appears as compliant.

[image]

The sensitivity label is configured in the following way:

[image]

However, when I access the SharePoint site, I get the following error that is supposed to be shown only for non compliant devices.

[image]

Do you know why this happens despite the device is considered compliant in Intune?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that you have also set up SharePoint to be accessible only to people in your organization. Are you using accounts of people in your organization? You can try logging into another account with this device to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi, I am testing with accounts of people inside my organization. Tried with several accounts, same problem.

Comment: Please take a look at this similar issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/purview-information-protection-sensitivity-button/aaf504f2-b035-48b2-baf4-157aa877d580